# This code did not work in ajax loading function but it works in normal php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddslick.js"></script>     

<div id="myDropdown"></div>     

 <?  
     $req = "SELECT firstname,id "  ."FROM user "   ."WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' ";  
     $query = mysql_query($req); 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  
    $results[] = array('text' => $row['firstname'],'value' => $row['id'],'selected' => 
    'false','description' => $row['firstname']); }   

     $r=json_encode($results);

    ?> 

<script>

     $('#myDropdown').ddslick({    
     data:<? echo $r?>,    
     width:300,    
     selectText: "Select your preferred social network",   
      imagePosition:"right",    
     onSelected: function(selectedData){         

     }   
     });     
</script>
```

Comment: You didn't close your `<script>` tag for one. How's it working?

Comment: Is the above code being called by an ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

Like user007 mentioned, you forgot the closing ">" for the last script block.

Also :

```
onSelected: function(selectedData){         //callback function: do something with selectedData;     }    });
```

Will throw an error as the comment "//calback" precedes the closing } }); tags, causing a parser to throw an Error as your code isn't formatted correctly, rendering it not runnable. A helpful tool for this is monitoring your browser console.